# Computing the Length of a finite length module.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How we can compute the length (length of a composition series)  of the Artinian local ring $R=K[x,y]/(x^3,y^3)$ ?

Does the following chain is a saturated chain of ideals of $K[x,y]$ ?

$(x^3,y^3)\subsetneq (x^3,x^2y^2, y^3) \subsetneq (x^3,x^2y,y^3) \subsetneq (x^3,x^2y,xy^2, y^3) \subsetneq (x^3,xy,y^3)\subsetneq (x^3,xy,y^2) \subsetneq (x^3,y) \subsetneq (x^2,y) \subsetneq (x,y).$

Comment: Hi Sadegh. Please show us what you tried so far by editting the question. As it stands, this question fails to meet the quality of questions expected on this site.

Comment: For a local artinian graded $K$-algebra $A$ we have $\operatorname{length}(A)=\dim_KA$. In your case this $9$. If I'm not mistaken, it seems that your chain is a little longer.

Comment: Note that $R \cong K[x]/x^3 \otimes_K K[y]/y^3$ as $K$-algebras (in particular as $K$-vector spaces).

Comment: @Dune Just wondering: your comment is a continuation of mine or you have some other ideas for computing the length?

Comment: @user26857: Yes, it is meant to be a continuation of your hint. With this in mind one has only to determine the dimension of $K[x]/x^3$ as $K$-vector space, which is just an application of a standard theorem.

Comment: You must add $K[x,y]$ at the end of your chain. The required length is $9$.